# How to save a sftp server connection in web.config?

Tags: c#, web-config, connection-string

Whats the best way to store sftp server connection credentials in web.config? It consists of 4 things:

- IP
- user
- password
- port

Thanks :-)

Comment: What are you doing with the information?

Comment: Reading it from my web app to connect to the sftp server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in the [`<appSettings>` section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx).

For example:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SFTP IP" value="127.0.0.1" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>

string ip = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTP IP"];
```

Comment: So I have 4 keys there? I was hoping there is a better way?

Comment: @Grady: Yes.  If you want to, you could use fewer keys and parse the strings, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: If you really want to, you could make your own ConfigSection, but it's probably not worth it.